# Set IIS8.5 log destination ( ETW )

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I want to script the destination of my IIS log files to be Both Log and ETW, but I can't find the setting name anywhere.

So far I have been able to set the default location for the log files, as well as a number of other settings, but I can't find any references through Google to tell me how in IIS8.5 to set the destination to Log and ETW.

I would expect it should look something like this:

```
New-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$siteName -name logfile.destination -value LogDestination.Log_And_ETW
```

or

```
New-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$siteName -name logfile.destination -value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   logman start myiistrace -p {DE4649C9-15E8-4FEA-9D85-1CDDA520C334} -ets
```

This will start a trace and log it to myiistrace.etl in the directory where you start it from. You can find the guid by running "logman providers"

Comment: That starts a logging session, but does not actually enable ETW logging in IIS.